# Jenkins automated creation of credentials

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I'm trying to have Jenkins in docker automatically build credentials when the build.

If I manually re-add the ssh private key to Jenkins the ssh works from GitHub but when a new image of Jenkins builds it does not work even with the same secrets/ folder

The secrets and ssh keys are copied into the /var/jenkins_home/secrets in the Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir /var/jenkins_home/.ssh
COPY .ssh/id_rsa /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY .ssh/id_rsa.pub /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then the secrets folder is copied as well as the credentials.xml

```
COPY secrets /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets
COPY credentials.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/credentials.xml
```

The credentials.xml folder's credential for the GitHub account linked to it needs to have a new private key attached but it does not like the one originally build to the secrets/ folder.

The credentials.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider plugin="credentials@2.3.7">
  <domainCredentialsMap class="hudson.util.CopyOnWriteMap$Hash">
    <entry>
      <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain>
        <specifications/>
      </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain>
      <java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
        <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey plugin="ssh-credentials@1.18.1">
          <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
          <id>github</id>
          <description></description>
          <username>github</username>
          <privateKeySource class="com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource">
            <privateKey>{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}</privateKey>
          </privateKeySource>
        </com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey>
      </java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
    </entry>
  </domainCredentialsMap>
</com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret is encrypted on disk.
At the script console in Jenkins use this script to decrypt the secret.

```
println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{<your secret key>}")
)
```